# What is Unicode Virtual Console?

Tags: tty

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then enter the terminal.
I want to input CJK(Chinese, Japanese, Korean) here.
This called unicode virtual console/terminal(according to the Wiki).
What is Unicode virtual console in detail?
How can I input CJK?

Comment: Do you want a book about what's the Unicode Virtual Console or just how to write CJK in the TTY?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/556993/how-to-display-unicode-in-a-linux-virtual-terminal 
refer this link it will help for you